What is the name of/where can I get this part?
Car is a 2018 ford kuga mk2.
The windscreen washers are not working so I was investigating and in the process lost the central black component where the t junction is.  In the first pic you can see the component is there but in the second you can see it’s no longer there because I dropped and lost it.  Now water is leaking out through the pipe going upwards to the washer jets.
Do you know what the name of this part is, where might I be able to find a part number and where can I buy a replacement part, preferably without buying the whole assembly.
Thanks



That looks like a windscreen washer check valve (windshield washer check valve in Yank-speak). It prevents washer fluid from flowing back to the tank by gravity between spritzes, and therefore it helps to give a more satisfying windcreen washing experience with immediate effect rather than waiting three seconds for the fluid from the tank to fill the tubing.
These are widely available in auto parts stores and online. You don't need an exact brand replacement as long as the fitting fits the tubing. The arrow on the check valve shows the direction of flow, i.e., toward the windscreen.
